# zip file (with spaces in the files name) to unzip and rename files and zip back

Tags: command-line, compression, zip, 7-zip

I'm trying to rename the contents of a zip file to match the name of the zip file with a batch file.

This is exactly what I'm trying to do : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22853824/zip-file-to-unzip-and-rename-files-and-zip-back/25732864#25732864

it works but only if the zip files do not have a space in the file name. Otherwise it creates a bunch of empty folders where a space occurs in the zip file name.

Phil V's answer works well but I think it just need refined a bit :

```
:: # Core Logic
:: # Looping through all the zips
for %%c in (*.zip) do (
    :: # Make a temporary folder with the same name as zip to house the zip content
    if not exist %%~nc md %%~nc
    :: # Extracting zip content into the temporary folder
    7z e -o%%~nc %%c
    if exist %%~nc (
        :: # Jump into the temporary folder
        pushd %%~nc
        if exist *.* (
            :: Loop through all the files found in the temporary folder and prefix it with the zip's name
            for %%i in (*.*) do (
                ren %%i %%~nc.%%i
            )
            :: # Zip all the files with the zip prefix with orginal zip name but with a number 2 (abc2.zip)
            if exist %%~nc.* (
                7z a -tzip %%~nc2 %%~nc.*
            )
            :: # Move the new zip back out of the tempory folder
            if exist %%~nc2.zip move %%~nc2.zip ..
        )
        :: # Jump out of the temporary folder
        popd
        :: # Showing you the directory listing
        dir
        :: # Showing you the content inside the new zip
        7z l %%~nc2.zip
        :: # Remove the temporary folder (Clean up)
        rd /s/q %%~nc
    )
)
```

Update : OK got it working with the help of webmarc (see solution below).

It took some trial and error but eventually I figured out where the quotes are needed to get it to work the way I need. Just like webmarc said "put quotes around any other arguments in your program that may have embedded spaces."

Comment: What is your actual question? How to make the script work with files that have spaces in them?

Comment: @Adam - yes that is my actual question, sorry. How to make the script work with files that have spaces in them?

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget, the shell doesn't know the difference between multiple arguments and files with a space in them.   You can use quotes to tell the shell when a single argument should have a space in it:

For example, `ren %%i %%~nc.%%i`, change to `ren "%%i" "%%~nc.%%i"`

And put quotes around any other arguments in your program that may have embedded spaces.